# iOS indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, indexing

I have two arrays, each containing strings. The first array is a list of words, the second array contains alternatives to those words in different languages.

The arrays are matched such that the word at index `n` in the second array is a translation of the word at index `n` in the first array.

The words and their translations are displayed in a table view. The user can filter the table view by entering text in a search field. When this is done, I create a filtered array from the first array like this:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText

[self.filteredarray removeAllObjects]; 
[firstarray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if ([obj compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])] == NSOrderedSame)
     {
         idx= [firstarray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:obj];
         NSUInteger maxindex = idx + 50;
         for (idx ; (idx < [firstarray count] && idx <= maxindex && idx!= NSNotFound); idx ++)
         {
             [self.filteredarray addObject:[firstarray objectAtIndex: idx]];
         }
         *stop = YES;
     }
 }];
```

Then, when I am displaying the values in my table view, I use the following code. This is an exerpt from my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I am trying to get the index from the original array using the object that has been added to the filtered array.

```
contentForThisRow = [self.filteredarray objectAtIndex:row];
NSUInteger index = [self.firstarray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:contentForThisRow];
contentForThisRow2 = [self.secondarray objectAtIndex:index];
```

This works on the simulator, but on the device I will sometimes get repeats of the same entry from the second array. For example, my first array contains the word "hello" three consecutive times, at indexes x, y and z. My second array contains "hei", "heisan" and "hoppsan", which are all translations of "hello", at indexes x, y and z.

On the simulator, I get three cells, each with a different translation. On the device, I get three cells, all with "hei", the first translation. This does not happen for all repeated translations.

Why is this happening, and how can I get around it?

Comment: @jrturton I deleted my previous question, because it was a mess. Now this is a more clear question.

Comment: @wagashi explain you problem clearly first, then add only relevant code snippets with any irrelevant code taken out. Makes it much easier to read/answer your question that way :)

Comment: @jturton Now I have edited my question and added more info. Anything more you want to know?

Comment: @Jordan Um, I think all my codes are relevant for this problem. Now I have edited my question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mess. Make your code minimal and come back - if that question then still exists!

Comment: @Eiko could you point out which part is a mess?

Comment: @jturton there are three "hello" in firstarray and three equivalents matches in secondarray, both indexes are same. The question is why it works on Simulator, but it is a bit messed up on iPhone?

Comment: @jturton I have implemented about thirty if/else if where *alphabet here* is a-z, i.e. @"a", @"b", @"c", etc. in the place of @"*alphabet here*".

Comment: Please sit down and review your code line-by-line.  To get the formatting correct, highlight the whole file, right-mouse-button, and select "re-indent".  Then go through and make sure you understand what every line does and why it's there.  Where variables are referenced, follow the control flow backwards to find where they're set, and make sure they're set the way you think.  Check your `if` conditions to make sure they make sense, you don't have `>` where you meant `<`, etc.  Likewise with loop control expressions.  Make sure your array indexing is zero-origin. Etc.

Comment: @wagashi I have edited your question to what I think are the bare essentials, if you think I have gone too far please let me know. I don't think you'd get a good response with it as it was before.

Comment: @daniel I will when I have time :) Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: @jrturton Thanks I appreciate your editing help. I wonder if anyone else has encountered this problem?

Comment: You wonder if other people have encountered bugs in their code??  Probably.

Comment: @daniel No, I meant the indexOfObjectIdenticalTo issue. It is supposed to work in my case, as it works with many sets of duplicates, except a few certain sets of duplicates.

Comment: That's because you have a bug in your code.  Trust me.

Comment: (Note that `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo` looks for that exact object address.  Since strings are sometimes cached (has nothing to do with compile/build caching) sometimes @"ABC" will have the same address as a "different" @"ABC", sometimes not.  More likely not with longer strings.  You probably don't want to be using `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo`.)

Comment: @Daniel Ok, but why does it work arbitrarily? I don't want strings to be cached, how to evade it? Do you mean index when you say object address?

Comment: You have no control over whether a common cached version of a string is used vs a separate unique version -- and you shouldn't care, since strings are immutable.  To "evade" it simply don't use `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo`.  (And when I said "object address" I meant "object address".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that iOS (on the device) may be using a slightly different optimisation to the emulator somewhere, either in NSString or NSArray. That is a guess.

indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: returns the index of the first object that has the same memory address as the object you are passing in. On the phone it appears to have re-used the identical string objects in your first array when building the filtered array (possibly even when building firstArray), so you are getting the same index value back each time.

A better solution would be to build your filtered array as an array of dictionaries, storing the values from the correct indexes of firstArray and secondArray at that point. You can then use these values directly when populating the cell instead of searching through both arrays again. This should also have some performance benefits.

You would achieve this using the following code. First, inside your loop when you are building the filtered array, instead of adding the object from firstarray, do this:

```
[self.filteredArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[firstarray objectAtIndex:idx],@"english",[secondarray objectAtIndex:idx],@"translated",nil];
```

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, to get your two content variables:

```
NSDictionary *rowData = [self.filteredarray objectAtIndex:row];
contentForThisRow = [rowData objectForKey:@"english"];
contentForThisRow2 = [rowData objectForKey:@"translated"];
```

An *even* better solution would be to hold your data like this in the first place, and not try to keep two separate arrays synchronised. I imagine if you want to add or alter anything in your two separate files you could quickly get them out of step. However, I feel I've done enough for the day...

Comment: Ok. It is strange that it is arbitrary, because only a few of duplicates don't show the desired results, otherwise other duplicates, including sets of three duplicates show the matched pairs on iOS.

Comment: It is strange, I agree. Probably why you've had a tough time explaining it here :)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to investigate in my case ;) I have added codes as you suggested, but I don't know how to add an array of two dictionaries, please see my new edit.

Comment: Btw, I even deleted the app on my device, and re-installed it. I even emptied caches and cleaned all targets in iOS and also resetted iOS Simulator. I also deleted the two source files with its references and imported them again, but it didn't help.

Comment: You seem to be really obsessing about cache.  I've maybe 3-4 times had cache muck me up when testing iPhone apps, but I've done thousands of builds.  Cache problems are rare, and mostly have to do with the Interface Builder and related components.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - it's the iOS development equivalent of repairing permissions - gets recommended on here when people have no other idea what might be wrong.

Comment: Or equivalent to the M$ helpline suggestion to reinstall Windoze.

Comment: @jrturton I am grateful for your help. I agree with your latest solution. However, I have been and am still busy, so I havent tested your solution yet. I will accept your answer after I have tested it. But I get the rough draft of your idea :) Btw, I have tested by removing second duplicate "hello", and the second cell from secondarray shows correct result, but third cell "hello" shows "hei" like the first cell. Strange, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

```
else

contentForThisRow = [self.firstarray objectAtIndex:row];
contentForThisRow2 = [self.secondarray objectAtIndex:row];
```

You see anything wrong with that?

Comment: I forgot adding curly brackets. I did edit my question. But otherwise than that, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @wagashi - Never mind editing the question, did you edit your code to include them?

Comment: @jturton yes I added the curly brackets in my codes now. Do you see them?